# Bootstrap 3 simple dropdown not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When trying to adjust to Bootstrap 3, I have encountered the following problem.

When I click on the button named `F`, I would like `Home` and `Not Home` to show up, but it does not at the moment.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=qpWlaOeGZ_4#t=374) is the video I am learning from.

```
<div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class= "navbar-brand">Jackdh</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> F 
        </button>
        <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Not Home</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you simply forgot to add `bootstrap.js` and also `jquery`. 
With that included, [everything works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/d5JDv/).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was using the link from their website incorrectly.

Comment: Not exactly same mistake, but get some clue and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

@op (original poster)

Marcel's answer gave me a clue so I checked my script tag

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I forgot to add the bootstrap javascript folder "js/"

With this script tag everything works fine.

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

@ Marcel - I couldn't vote up your answer due to lack of reputaion!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add navbar-header div after container, Try this one !

`   
            
                Brand

```
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>`
```