# Angularjs bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Am bit new to angularjs and bootstrap.

Am trying to add a simple dropdown. But it is not working.

Tried out the suggestion @ [Bootstrap 3 simple dropdown not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966079/bootstrap-3-simple-dropdown-not-working). That is also not working.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ui-sref="a">a<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a ui-sref="a">a</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="b">b</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="c">c</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="d">d</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="e">e</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="f">f</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="g">g</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="h">h</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="i">i</a></li>         
  <li><a ui-sref="j">j</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="k">k</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Complete code @ http://plnkr.co/edit/uFDFOJfHjL5qY9nVEykq?p=preview

Hope someone would help me out.

Comment: Since the current answer is not valid anymore, maybe @Pals can switch the selected answer to #2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add on-toggle to your anchor tag, to avoid conflicts between bootstrap dropdown angular dropdown class, this issue is a closed on angular-ui(https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2156)

Comment: This was a lifesaver, particularly if you are using older Angular sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 75):

NOTE: Most answers here are outdated! The main issue is that the `dropdown` directive is **not available as a class anymore, but only as an attribute**, and that it has been renamed to `uib-dropdown`.

I was stuck here for a while, but changing the class into an attribute worked as a charm.

Also, you need to use the **'uib-'** prefix for each directive instead of plain names.

```
<li uib-dropdown>
    <a uib-dropdown-toggle>a<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a ui-sref="a">a</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="b">b</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="c">c</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="d">d</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

(And of course, make sure you did not forget to include the ui.bootstrap module in your app.)

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: Just a note that beginning with the 1.0 release we've required a uib- prefix for all our directives and have physically removed support for the old directive names due to namespace clashes and native browser elements.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I was going to add that. Else you get deprecation warnings in the console.

Comment: Well, my point was that the deprecated code (and the warnings) are all removed starting at 1.0 so you wouldn't see them anymore and your code won't work.  A double whammy.

Comment: This needs to be updated as the new correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Pals, if you agree with Kode_12, could you please move the accepted answer to this entry instead of the one currently selected (with less votes)? Make StackOverflow a better place :-)

Answer (score 32):

You need to include `ui.bootstrap` module in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
```

and also remove `ui-sref` from the dropdown trigger.

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >a<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h92n3gyY8sTkXMigvrzJ?p=preview)**

Comment: wasted 30min because of ui.bootstrap module. +1

Comment: @PSL seems like a great opportunity to add some docs to help others avoid the same pitfall.

Comment: Just a note that beginning with the 1.0 release we've required a `uib-` prefix for all our directives and have physically removed support for the old directive names due to namespace clashes and native browser elements.

Comment: Please note this answer is not valid for recent editions of UI-Bootstrap, since uib-dropdown needs to be an attribute, not a class. As discussed in the often mentioned Github issue 2156.

Comment: This solution is not working in mobile browsers. is there any alternate solution for mobile browsers @PSL ?

Answer (score 8):

`data-toggle="dropdown"` should be removed.  I guess it creates some conflict with `ui.bootstrap`

```
<li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
            <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle href="" role="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
              Events
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                <a href="">Event 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Event 2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great resource from [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) regarding the subject, as I had the same issue. I'll outline what I did below.

1. Download [ui bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages)
2. Move zipped file to target directory for app, and unzip
3. locate the latest edition of the ui bootstrap release, which in my case, is located at "bootstrap-gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"
4. Include the minified js file in your main .html file:
   `<script src='stylesheets/bootstrap-gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js'></script>`
5. Go back to [Angular directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and scroll down to the dropdown section. Copy their javascript into your primary js file and html samples and customize as usual

That's what did it for me. Hope that helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you included ui.bootstrap module in your app

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['other inclusions','ui.bootstrap']);
```

Then if the problem still persists don't use dropdown-toggle and dropdown as directives. Instead use as class. i.e. class = 'dropdown-toggle' etc.

For Example :

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-append-to-body">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Dropdown on Body <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Refer this issue. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2156

Answer (score 0):

Worked out pretty simple the solution (after trying to find it for ages) Simply add "dropdown-toggle" directive to your button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary " dropdown-toggle type="button">Drop Me Down<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I noticed that the attribute "dropdown" need to be added to the li element, once that is added, everything will be fine.

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown>
   <a href="#" dropdown-toggle role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">... <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       ...
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Angular 2:

1. add npm install ng2-bootstrap --save
2. then follow the example from GITHUB:
   https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/demo/components/dropdown