# Angular Bootstrap Dropdown not working in Angular Fullstack

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-fullstack

I have copied code directly form the [Angular Bootstrap UI Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNlXoa)

I am using a blank Angular FullStack (Mean) template for building an application.

When I use the code from the Angular Bootstrap `uib-dropdown` it ends up formatted incorrectly and does not work, all other angular bootstrap components seem to work fine

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: How it Looks in Angular FullStack]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgrade Angular UI in bower.json:

```
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
```

Then run:

```
bower install
```

Comment: This should be the answer! Thanks!

Comment: This  breaks the navbar. To fix it you will need to edit navbat.html and change <div collapse...> to <div uib-collapse...>

Comment: In my case I also had to tweak <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu"> to read: <ul uib-dropdown-menu>. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved my problem by not using the Angular Bootstrap Dropdown directive and gone with Bootstrap + Plain Old Angular code which I googled.

This is working fine for me.

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="btn-group" ng-class='{open: open}'>
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                    ng-click='open=!open'>
                Action<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="choice in ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']"
                    ng-click="setChoiceIndex($index);$parent.open =!$parent.open">
                    <a href="#">{{choice}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't close the dropdown when you click elsewhere in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I updated Angular UI Bootstrap to 0.14.3 version & then resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'uib-' prefix for each directive, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725928/3439101